# Using Configurable Map Viewer with Angular Application?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, angularjs

I have Angular JS application with WEB API RESET service
i tired to take sample from CMV Viewer and applied some feathers like search , print, legend  and included many layers from Our oracle DB

my case   :
I developed search screen in Angular JS application and want to display results on map

so how can using CMV viewer in my Angular application if someone use it before or any suggest ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question to provide some details about what you have tried with respect to researching/testing prior to posting your question, please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really want to use the CMV viewer *in* an Angular application. The CMV viewer is an application framework, just like Angular. The CMV widgets (search, print, legend, etc) are typically just a wrapper around modules from the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/).

I would suggest using the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) directly in your Angular application. There are a few examples of how to do this on GitHub:

- https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map
- https://github.com/tomwayson/angular-parcel-map